# material ui: reactjs: tablecell: width fit to content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code. Its same as the [basic table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#basic-table) from material ui. Only thing i have modified the First row, second column content. I am using a Grid element inside it. and also added more columns so that i can see a horizontal scroll scenario

I dont want it to break.

```
import React from 'react';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { createMuiTheme, makeStyles, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const hare = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 650,
  },
});

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}


const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt',
        159,
        <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="space-between" spacing={10}>
          <Grid item>
             Dont
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            Break
          </Grid>
        </Grid>,
        24,
        4.0
  ),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];



export default function BasicTable() {
  const classes = hare();

  return (
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows.map((row) => (
              <TableRow key={row.name}>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {row.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

What is see is

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `wrap="nowrap"` prop on the `Grid`. From the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/):

> `wrap` - Defines the flex-wrap style property. It's applied for all screen sizes.

Just the excerpt that I've changed, and the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-keller-ebe3j?file=/demo.js:762-925)

```
<Grid container wrap="nowrap" alignItems="center" justify="space-between" spacing={10}>
  <Grid item>Dont</Grid>
  <Grid item>Break</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Also if i am trying to have no wrap for first column heading. I  try `<TableCell wrap="nowrap">Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>`. Still the text is wrapped. How can i have nowrap for this also

Comment: `TableCell` is a `th/td` under the hood I guess. You could use add a `white-space: nowrap;` if you like